# CallLog.Calls.getLastOutgoingCall Error in Api 15

Tags: android, logging, call

i tried to get last outgoing call contact , so when used:

```
CallLog.Calls.getLastOutgoingCall
```

but error occurred. the api level is 15, i tested it in android api 22 and worked fine(In Documentation said It added in api 8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, just add below to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.read_contacts" />
```